# PHP form redirect if get elseif else

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have an HTML web form where the customer can select the report they want to print. Now, I must get the value from the select menu and redirect the customer to the correct report page.

Example:

```
<form action="print-report.php" name="print" method="get" target="_blank">
    <select name="period">
        <option value="daily" selected>Daily Report</option>
        <option value="anual">Anual Report</option>
        <option value="weekly">Weekly Report</option>
        <option value="monthly">Montly Report</option>  
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Print Report"></form>
```

Now in the other page, I must get the type of report the customer needs and redirect them to the correct page, but I don't know how.

```
<?php
    if get daily redirect to daily.php
    elseif get weekly redirect to weekly.php
<?php
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what about when you get monthly? will it also redirect to monthly.php??

Comment: yes, it will redirect to daily, weekly, montly and yearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit data using PHP through a **form using the POST or GET method**, the form data will be **passed via the $_POST or $_GET array** respectively which is accessible by your PHP file. The key for both arrays will be the name of your form element.

Hence, to obtain the value of the selected drop-down list, you can have something like this in your PHP code:

```
<?php
    $SelectedValue = $_GET['period'];
    if($SelectedValue == "daily")        { header("Location: daily.php"); }
    else if($SelectedValue == "weekly")  { header("Location: weekly.php"); }
    // add your other options and redirects here
?>
```

Though it's worth noting that you might be interested in using a **switch-case statement** too:

```
<?php
    switch($_GET['period'])
    {
        case "daily":  header("Location: daily.php");  break;
        case "weekly": header("Location: weekly.php"); break;
        // add your other options and redirects here
        default:       header("Location: error.php");  break;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check what you receive from `$_GET` method and then redirect to specific page (for example):

```
if ($_GET['period'] == 'daily') {
    // redirect to daily
} else {
    // redirect to other
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in print-report.php:

```
$url = $_GET["print"];

if($url == 'daily' || $url == 'weekly' || $url == 'monthly' || $url == 'yearly'){

   header("Location: {$url}.php");
}else{
   header("Location: 404.php");  // I just added this line to check for url param doesn't match your script name.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying:

```
if ($_GET['period'] == 'daily') {
    header('Location: daily.php');
} else if ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery also to redirect directly from your html page.
Here is your code :

```
<form action="daily.php" name="print" method="get" target="_blank">
   <select id="select_report" name="period">
      <option value="daily" selected>Daily Report</option>
      <option value="anual">Anual Report</option>
      <option value="weekly">Weekly Report</option>
      <option value="monthly">Montly Report</option>  
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Print Report">
</form>
```

I have just added an id to select box`id="select_report"` and set form action to "daily.php" because daily value is select by default.

now just use jquery cdn and this script for redirection-

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#select_report").on('change', function(){
var x = $("#select_report").val();
if(x=="daily")
{
    $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'daily.php');
}
else if(x=="anual")
{
    $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'annual.php');
}
else if(x=="weekly")
{
    $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'weekly.php');
}
else if(x=="monthly")
{
    $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'monthly.php');
}
})
</script>
```